# When editing hosts file with vi , the added line gets repeated ad infinitum

Tags: linux, vim, vi, hosts-file

Sometimes when I edit the hosts file by adding a new line, and when I do <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>:</kbd>, <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>Q</kbd> to save and exit, that line gets repeated infinite times in the file, and then gets saved.

What am I doing wrong?

Also, after this happens, what does one do to fix the situation? I tried deleting by pressing <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, but it's like a hydra-headed monster, for each line I delete a new one pops up from below.

Comment: Are you sure it's not just a broken terminal?

Comment: @DanielBeck -- Could be! I don't know for sure yet.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't happen with any other file? Any other editor or just vi(m)?

Comment: Infinite times... wow, I'd sell that hard drive on eBay... the NSA might be interested :-) Okay, how many lines, and does this also affect other files / a copy of the hosts file in `/tmp`??

Comment: @IngoKarkat -- good one! ok -- not "infinite times", just "as far as the eye can see" :)

Comment: @slhck -- I've only used vi with the hosts file so far (I'm not sure I'm allowed to say it, but I really despise vi -- so I generally avoid it as much as I can)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug, it's a feature!

almost all commands can accept an address, or a count including a, i, o, S, A, s, and I. I mention these commands because they are insert commands, and all can add multiple lines pin preceded by a count. for example if you cancel or finish the previous command by pressing escape, and miss and press 1 two or more times the next command could be repeated 11 or 111 times causing the problem you are seeing.